# Is possible ask for an acces token oauth2 just with refresh token in spring security? without basic authentication?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I would like to know if in spring oauth2 is possible get a new pair tokens (access token and refresh token) just using another refresh token, without the basic authentication (without clientId and clientSecret, is there any way?

For exemple:

**WITH BASIC AUTH**

curl -u clientId:clientSecret -X POST 'http://myapplication.oauth2/accounts/oauth/token?grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=<CLIENT_ID>&refresh_token=' -v

**WITHOUT BASIC AUTH**

curl -u -X POST 'http://myapplication.oauth2/accounts/oauth/token?grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=<CLIENT_ID>&refresh_token=' -v

I note that sprint BasicAuthenticationFilter in spring uses validation bellow, maybe override this filter and make the authentication just with refresh token.

```
String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");

if (header == null || !header.toLowerCase().startsWith("basic ")) {
  chain.doFilter(request, response);
  return;
}
```

Comment: I'm very interested how this question can be solved.

Comment: @georgecro why do you want to refresh an access token without Client authentication (without client id and client secret)? OAuth 2.0 specification requires Client authentication for this case.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a workaround

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no. The class used to manage the Spring Oauth 2 endpoints is the following one:

```
@FrameworkEndpoint
public class TokenEndpoint extends AbstractEndpoint
```

Both requests, I mean, get `access token` and `refresh` one use the same endpoint with different parameters. And the method to manage those ones is:

```
@RequestMapping(
  value = {"/oauth/token"},
  method = {RequestMethod.POST}
)
public ResponseEntity<OAuth2AccessToken> postAccessToken(Principal principal, @RequestParam Map<String, String> parameters) throws HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException {
  if (!(principal instanceof Authentication)) {
    throw new InsufficientAuthenticationException("There is no client authentication. Try adding an appropriate authentication filter.");
  } else {
    String clientId = this.getClientId(principal);
    ...
```

As you can see, a `Principal` object is required (in this case provided by the Basic Authentication).

Even, if you configure the security of your project to permit that url without checking authentication, you will achieve to "enter" in above method but you will receive an `InsufficientAuthenticationException` because no `Authentication` instance has been provided.

---

### Why custom authentication will not work

**1.** Create a custom `AuthenticationProvider` will not work because the method `postAccessToken` is invoked before. So you will receive an `InsufficientAuthenticationException`.

**2.** Create a `OncePerRequestFilter` and configure it to execute before process the current request:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http...
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .addFilterBefore(myCustomFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
      web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers(POST, "/accounts/oauth/**");
    }
```

with a code "similar to":

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    ...
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("existingUser",
                    "passwordOfExistingUser",
                    Collections.emptyList()));
    ...
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

The problem with this approach is **the principal in `TokenEndpoint` comes from the `HttpServletRequest` not from Spring context**, as you can see debugging `BasicAuthenticationFilter` class.

In your custom filter you can try, using reflection, set a value in `userPrincipal` property but, as you can verify, `request` has several "internal `request` properties" and that could be a "too tricky option".

---

In summary, Oauth standard needs user/pass to access to the resources, if you want to workaround in almost of provided endpoints maybe that project is not what you are looking for.

---

### Workaround to include your own object in Spring Principal

I do not recommend that but if you still want to go ahead with this approach, there is a way to include your own value inside the `principal` parameter received by `TokenEndpoint` class.

It is important to take into account **`BasicAuthorizationFilter` will be still executed**, however you will be able to override the Spring principal object by your own one.

For this, we can reuse the previous `CustomAuthenticationFilter` but now your have to include the filters you need, I mean, allowed urls, parameters, etc You are going to "open the doors", so be careful about what you allow and not.

The difference in this case is, instead of add the configuration in our class that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` we are going to do it in:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private CustomAuthenticationFilter customAuthenticationFilter;
  ...

  @Override
  public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) {
    security.checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    security.addTokenEndpointAuthenticationFilter(customAuthenticationFilter);
  }
  ...
```

Comment: I have one idea: I see that I can set `http.csrf().disable().authenticationProvider(.....)` What if I implement custom Authentication instance?

Comment: Also in such cases how did you managed to implement this refresh token functionality?

Comment: I have updated my answer with more information. `how did you managed...` because in my case, that microservice is not invoked directly from a "Frontend application", I managed it with a "backend - backend communication". On the other hand, in the same way you need to send an "application user/pass" (I'm talking about an "application credentials", not an specific one for a user of your application), if you need to send those requests from a "Frontend application", you need to keep sending those data in the request when get access token or refresh one is required.

Comment: ok, so what about this idea. I can store the user and pass along with access_token and refresh_token into the Angular SPA. Is it too risky? I will check is it possible to encrypt them.

Comment: `Is it too risky?` yes, that is a bad idea, because the payload of a JWT token (really a JWS one) is a "base64 value" of the information you are including on it (more information in https://jwt.io/)

Comment: When you use Spring Oauth 2, you usually will manage two types credentials: **1.** The user/pass of your Frontend application **2.** The clientId/pass of your Oauth 2 server. It is up to you decide if both ones will be "the same" or not. As I told you in other comment, when you start to increase the "required customizations" of a "dependency project", maybe you need to think if create your own one is a better option.

Comment: About this: `the clientId/pass of your Oauth 2 server`. I can set then here: https://github.com/rcbandit111/OAuth2/blob/master/src/main/java/org/engine/security/UserClientDetailsService.java#L43 but it's not clear to me how I can use them later on. Can you describe it a little but?