# Revoke Oauth2 token without using Basic Auth

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to implement the example from the book [OAuth-2.0-Cookbook](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/OAuth-2.0-Cookbook/blob/master/Chapter04/revoke-server/src/main/java/com/packt/example/revokeserver/oauth/revoke/TokenRevocationController.java) using Spring cloud OAuth2.

I managed to implement his functionality but unfortunately I'm facing a problem: In order to make successful call I have to provide basic authentication credentials(`Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46cXdlcnR5`):

```
@PostMapping("/oauth/revoke")
public ResponseEntity<String> revoke(@RequestParam Map<String, String> params) {
    RevocationService revocationService = revocationServiceFactory
            .create(params.get("token_type_hint"));

    revocationService.revoke(params.get("token"));

    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

Github [source](https://github.com/rcbandit111/OAuth2/blob/master/src/main/java/org/engine/rest/TokenRevocationController.java#L23)

I like the idea to have some kind of authentication when POST request is made to revoke a token but I don't think that Angular SPA app should hold the username and password all the time in order to make a successful call to `/oauth/revoke`.

In general the solution on Google have the just a endpoint which accept only token. For that cases I don't know what solution can be appropriate.

How I can remove the basic authentication functionality into Spring Cloud OAuth2? I use this security config:

```
http
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            // Configure token authentication permissions
            .requestMatchers().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/oauth/token")
                .and()
            // Configure token revoke permissions
            .requestMatchers().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/oauth/revoke")
                .and()
            .httpBasic()
                .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
```

Github [source](https://github.com/rcbandit111/OAuth2/blob/master/src/main/java/org/engine/security/WebSecurityConfig.java#L40):

Comment: Take a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62955162/is-possible-ask-for-an-acces-token-oauth2-just-with-refresh-token-in-spring-secu/63209551

Answer (score 0):

you can disable the authetication for revoke endpoint like this

```
http
...
.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers("/oauth/revoke").permitAll()
...
```

Comment: I tried this: https://pastebin.com/z3691x1Ebut I get ` Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't configure antMatchers after anyRequest`