# Configure basic auth for /oauth/token

Tags: oauth-2.0, spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I want to implement token refresh for OAuth2 using Spring Cloud.

I can create token by sending request to `/oauth/token` using this payload:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/engine/oauth/token' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46cXdlcnR5' \
--form 'username=admin' \
--form 'password=qwerty' \
--form 'grant_type=password' \
--form 'scope=read'
```

But for refresh token the same path `/oauth/token` is used. I need to send also username and password into the header `'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46cXdlcnR5'`which I don't have them. I can create a new token using using refresh token with this payload:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/engine/oauth/token' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46cXdlcnR5' \
--form 'grant_type=refresh_token' \
--form 'scope=read' \
--form 'refresh_token=....'
```

Do you know how this issue can be solved?

Github [code](https://github.com/rcbandit111/OAuth2/blob/master/src/main/java/org/engine/security/WebSecurityConfig.java#L46)

Comment: Take a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62955162/is-possible-ask-for-an-acces-token-oauth2-just-with-refresh-token-in-spring-secu/63209551

Answer (score 1):

The refresh token grant message does not need an Authorization header. Try removing it and sending client_id as a form parameter instead. You may also need to configure the offline_access scope for token refresh to work.

The last I remember though, token refresh is not supposed to be supported for ROPC, though that behaviour may not be the same for all providers.

Finally, be aware that ROPG is not really recommended if you have better options. [This post](https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Why-the-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-Grant-Type-is-not-Authentication-nor-Suitable-for-Modern-Applications) summarises the issues.

If you can summarise your usage scenario I may be able to recommend a better alternative.

Comment: I get `    "error_description": "Invalid scope: offline_access",`

Comment: You need to configure that scope in the Authorization Server first, then send it from the client. Still no guarantees it will work with ROPG, where you are supposed to send credentials each time by default.

Comment: About the usage scenario: I have a Angular SPA which needs to be able to connect to Spring Cloud app and get some data using OAuth2 security. I need to have a token refresh and token revoke. See the link to the project to see what I have done so far.

Comment: Ah - you have a server side web app doing the security. The Authorization Code Flow is correct for that case - as in [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-authorization-code-flow).

Comment: My preference though is to do security client side in the SPA, which can have many architectural advantages. If interested in this approach, maybe discuss with your colleagues and see my [Blog Articles](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/08/goal-1-requirements/)

Comment: I set the scope here: https://github.com/rcbandit111/OAuth2/blob/master/src/main/java/org/engine/security/UserClientDetailsService.java#L45   Do I need to add something more?

Comment: You should aim to avoid building the Authorization Server yourself, since it is a highly complex thing. Instead use a low cost cloud option, then point your UIs and APIs to it. To see what a normal Authorization Server looks like and how to configure the offline_access scope against a client application, see [this post of mine](https://authguidance.com/2019/09/15/developer-domain-setup/). If you have to, then find the equivalent place in your own Auth Server.

Comment: thanks for the advice. Looking at my code do you see some configuration issue?

Comment: The scope array set via setScope should include offline_access I think - in addition to read / write. The scope details must be set against the client_id of the client app. I wouldn't know where that is in your tech stack.

Comment: I have update the code and test it but I get `"error_description": "There is no client authentication. Try adding an appropriate authentication filter."` Looks like it's expecting authorization. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Gary what do you think? Any solution?